# How to add numbers in a sequence up to user input than add one?

Tags: python

I'm taking an online introductory computer science class for Python. A homework problem says the inventor of chess asked for a grain of rice. 1 grain on the first day, 2 on the second, four grains on the third day, eight on the fifth day...all the way to 68 days. I have to create a function that does this, returning the number of grains for the number of squares entered.

I believe all I have to do is get the number of squares from user. Add up all the multiples of two up to the point of the user's input then sum by one. I have no idea how to do this. That's whats irritating; you can know what to do, but not how to do it.

```
def function(li):
    for i in range(len(li))
    #I need a loop that adds all the multiples of 2 up to the point of the user's input than returns that value. 
    function()
```

Comment: It isn't squaring, it is doubling each time.  Write out in "pseudo-code" (plain English) how you think it should work and we can help make it work like that.

Comment: This is a math question, not a Python question, really. Doubling up every square is simply a powers-of-two calculation. There is a [Python operator for that](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator).

Comment: Thanks for replying! You're right it's power of two! I think it should work like this:                                                                                                              get input from user,

return value of exponet minus one of user input,

Example: if user input=4
 then program computes 2**3

Comment: afaik thats just the number of grains on the 3rd day

Comment: @JoranBeasley, actually that's the number of grains on day 4. I think my answer has a reasonable explanation on how this should be calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same can be accomplished by looking at the sequence `1,2,4,8...`as `2^0,2^1,2^2,2^3...` you can create a simple function  that will give you the amount based on the number of days.

```
def fun(days):
    return 2**(days-1)

print fun(64)
9223372036854775808
```

Comment: Thanks! It's amazing how simple it is!

Comment: Yeah i remember I had the same problem in a math class and the answer was just to look at the sequence pattern

Comment: @TannerLancaster if this is the answer you were looking for, could you accept it?

Comment: Yes, how do I do that? I'm new here.

Comment: I clicked the check mark. Thank you very much. It wouldn't let me vote the answer up, though.

Comment: @TannerLancaster Yeah, you need more rep. points to up vote answers.

Answer (score 0):

As per your logic the grains start at 1 and keep doubling from the previous day

first day: 1 (2**0)

second day: 2 (2**1)

third day: 4 (2**2)

fourth day: 8 (2**3)

So on the fourth day there will be a total of `2**0 + 2**1 + 2**2 + 2**3`

Using the formula:

```
x**0 + x**1 + x**2 + x**3 .. x**m =  (x**(m+1) - 1)/(x-1)
```

we get `2**(m+1) -1` when `x =2`

So on the fourth day (i.e. m=3 since we started with zero based index) the total grains would be `2**4 -1 =15`

Based on above logic your function should be:

```
def totalGrains(days):
    return 2**days - 1
```